# Parsing logfiles in subdir

Tags: powershell

I have to parse some logfiles in a given directory and subdirectorys. I tried to use it with the following command: "gci -Recurse -File * | cat |select-string -Pattern myPattern".
So I get every line with "myPattern".

But I would like to get the file with the full pathname an the three leading and following lines.

Comment: You don't need `cat` as `Select-String` can open files --> `gci -Recurse -File | select-string -Pattern 'myPattern'`

Comment: [1] the `matchobject` returned by `Select-String` has a bunch of properties. one of them is the path of the file. ///// [2] one of the parameters of `Select-String` is `-Context`. it allows you to get the leading/trailing lines.